# Duration time in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What is the best class to represent a duration time in Ruby?

I'm writing a Run model that have `distance` and `duration` attributes.

If I want to work with minutes and seconds, the most indicated class would be `time`. However it has not just minutes and seconds, but also day, month, etc. What would be the proper way to store time duration in Ruby?

I'll need to do calculations with it later, e.g., average pace = duration/distance, and the result should be in the minutes format, i.e., 5'30", and not 5.50 min.

Comment: there is a [basic timeframe library](https://github.com/rossmeissl/timeframe) - it's aimed at periods of a day or more - but if you submitted some failing tests for your case, i'm sure the authors (my co-worker and I) would give it a try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use something like this to calculate how long a `Resque` job runs:

```
start = Time.now
#code goes here
finish = Time.now
seconds = sprintf("%0.02f", (finish - start) % 60)
minutes = (((finish - start) / 60) % 60).to_i
```

In this example, I'm going out to hundredths of a second, but you could tweak that if needed and possibly get rid of the `sprintf` all together if you wanted.  That would leave you with basically `seconds = (finish - start) % 60`  Then a simple `puts #{minutes}'#{seconds}"` would get you the output you want.

Answer (score 1):

`Time.now.to_f`,  `Time.now.to_i`,  `Time.now.to_r` give you a number of seconds since Epoch (1970), so you can find duration just subtracting two values.

**UPDATE** Probably the only difference between explicit conversion and @Eugene's suggestion is precision control if you need nanosecond resolution.